# Progressive upgrade of a RAID array

Tags: hard-drive, raid, sata, hardware-raid

Our group has a 16 disk backup RAID6 array. Currently, those 16 disks have the following specs;

- 500 GB
- 16 and 64MB cache
- 3 Gb/s SATA

I would like to begin upgrading these disks if possible, primarily for storage. In a perfect world I would be able to swap out older disks with a similar setup but much greater storage, e.g.

- 2 TB
- 64MB cache
- 3 Gb/s SATA (the write speed is not a big deal as writing occurs pretty infrequently)

However, I guess that having different sizes drives in a RAID array is a bad idea, so does anyone have an suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: You would have to partition the 2TB drives in 500GB chunks.

Comment: @MaxMackie You seen, I was thinking about that, but would that work with hardware RAID? The disk still has a single point of access to the RAID controller, but the disk controller would have to provide access to the four partitions as if they were four separate drives - can it do that? Would that not also reduce the SATA speed to 0.75 Gb/s per partition or worse, actually?

Comment: Hmmm, good questions. Unfortunately I've never dealt with hardware RAID so I'm not too sure what would happen.